# Restriction resizing browser JQuery

Tags: jquery, browser

I want my users to resize the browser only up to 400px.

It can do this with JQuery?

I needed a short example.

Comment: Absolutely not. The browser is a sandbox that contains and executes javascript. The language has no power over the box that contains it. However, you can limit your page's width with `body {min-width : 400px}`, that may add scrollbars.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/04fLy8t4/) implemented function which trig two events on user DOM element:

```
resizestart
resizeend
```

Code:

```
var resizeEventsTrigger = (function () {
    function triggerResizeStart($el) {
        $el.trigger('resizestart');
        isStart = !isStart;
    }

    function triggerResizeEnd($el) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
            $el.trigger('resizeend');
            isStart = !isStart;
        }, delay);
    }

    var isStart = true;
    var delay = 200;
    var timeoutId;

    return function ($el) {
        isStart ? triggerResizeStart($el) : triggerResizeEnd($el);
    };

})();

$("#my").on('resizestart', function () {
    console.log('resize start');
});
$("#my").on('resizeend', function () {
    console.log('resize end');
});

window.onresize = function () {
    resizeEventsTrigger( $("#my") );
};
```